# CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY after insert,after update

Tags: trigger

i want to insert,update two custom fields in an object. i wrote trigger

```
trigger availableLeavesTrigger on Leave_Request__c (after insert,after UPDATE) {
List<id> lrs=new List<id>();
List<Leave_request__c> lea=new List<Leave_request__c>();
for(Leave_Request__c leave:Trigger.New)
{
  lrs.add(leave.id);
}
List<Leave_request__c> lc=[select id,name,available_casual_leaves__c,available_sick_leaves__c,days_off__c,type_of_leave__C from leave_request__c where id =:lrs ];
for(Leave_Request__c leave:lc)
{
    if(leave.type_of_leave__C=='casual leave')
    {
        leave.available_casual_leaves__c=leave.available_casual_leaves__c-leave.days_off__c;    
        lea.add(leave);   
    }
    else if(leave.type_of_leave__c=='sick leave')
    {
        leave.available_sick_leaves__c=leave.available_sick_leaves__c-leave.days_off__c;
        lea.add(leave);
    }
 }
update lea;
}
```

I just cant able to insert or update the values into the fields. could anyone help me out

Answer (score 1):

You should write before Trigger for this instead of after trigger

```
trigger AvailableLeavesTrigger on Leave_Request__c (before insert,before update) {
    for(Leave_Request__c leave: Trigger.New)  {
        if('casual leave' == leave.Type_of_Leave__c){
            leave.Available_Casual_leaves__c-=leave.Days_Off__c;    
        }else if('sick leave' == leave.Type_of_Leave__c){
            leave.Available_Sick_Leaves__c-=leave.Days_Off__c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Atul's approach will work well if Days_Off is not a formula.  Otherwise, you may need to requery for the list of Leave_Request__c records.  Another approach you could take instead of a trigger, is to implement this rather easily using workflow and field updates.